# Swift: Retrieving data from a plist with a for in loop

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I am new to Swift and am having trouble retrieving information in a plist (see image), specifically in terms of iterating over the content and comparing the plist to user input. I have a

> "Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence Type'

error in my code.

```
func matchTraveller(location: Destination, preference: TravellingPreference) -> String{
    var message = ""
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Locals", ofType: "plist"){
        if let map = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path){
            if let locals = map["Local"] as? String {
                for local in locals{ // <-- ERROR HERE
                    let city = local["City"]
                    if local["City"] == location {
                        message = "We have matched you with \(local) in \(city)."
                    } else{
                        message = "Apologies, there aren't any locals registered in \(city) on LocalRetreat. Try again soon!"
                        break
                    }
                    if local["Preference"] == preference{
                        let prefer = local["Preference"]
                        message += "\(local) is also a \(prefer)"
                    }
                    return message
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQWRu.png)

[Plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kU2R.png)

Comment: Don't post your code as an image. Put back the actual text. Same for the plist.

Comment: Read the error. `locals` is a `String` yet you are trying to iterate over it like an array.

Answer (score 2):

You are telling Swift that `locals` is a string. I think you meant to define it as `[String]`.

```
if let locals = map["Local"] as? String {
```

Change to:

```
if let locals = map["Local"] as? [String] {
```

Your plist data does not match the code. What you have in the plist is a dictionary of array of String.

```
[String: [String]]
```

The code is attempting to access it as dictionary of array of dictionary of string: string.

```
[String: [String: String]]
```

You can either modify the plist data or change the code.  Which one would you like?

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I'm now receiving an error "Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'String' everywhere that I try to access the values in local, e.g., local["City"], local["Preference"]. Do you know how I can access the plist?

Comment: `local` is an array, not a dictionary. You access a value by an integer index, for example, `local[3]`

Comment: Looks to me that your plist data is incorrectly structured if you want to access it using that code.

Answer (score -1):

You need to define the type you are expecting.

It looks like you're expecting `locals` to be an array of dictionaries (either `[String: String]` or `[String: AnyObject]`, so try casting `map["Local"]` to that (i.e. `[[String: String]]`).

Ultimately a plist is a way to serialise structured data. You need to understand the structure you're dealing with before you can start working you way through one.